# ListView selector color selects all object, not each item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, colors, selector

I've done a ListView and filled it with a custom adapter, now I want to show what element is selected with a different color, so I made a drawer_list_selection.xml with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/primaryDark" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/primary" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/grey_soft" />
</selector>
```

Then, I set up my ListView background to this file:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" android:id="@+id/section_list"
    android:background="@drawable/drawer_list_selector" />
```

My problem is that when i press one section (one element) the entire ListView turn @color/primary and the activated method neither works. Any solution? Maybe is problem of my adapter?. Here is btw:

```
public class adaptadorLista extends ArrayAdapter<Secciones>{
    public adaptadorLista(Context context, Secciones[] section){
        super(context,0,section);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, null);

        ImageView img= (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.imageView_section);
        img.setImageResource(section[position].getIcon());
        TextView txt_section = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/Jaapokki-Regular.otf");
        txt_section.setTypeface(tf);
        txt_section.setText(section[position].getSec());
        return (item);
    }
}
```

The custom xml for the View:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    >
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp" android:background="@drawable/drawer_list_selector">
        <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView_section" android:src="@drawable/ic_d" android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:maxHeight="20dp" android:maxWidth="20dp" android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="hi" android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#000"
            />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set Your selector to android:listSelector. Not listview Background

Comment: Sorry, It's not working...Only colors the element, not the total width

Comment: Remove this line `android:background="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"` from your `ListView`. You need to add the selector only for the items not the whole list.

Comment: Yes, I've done it, but now, If I put the background on the element of the custom view (TextView in this case) just colors the space of the TextView, not the entire width of ListView. The TextView layout_width is set to fill parent to, in theory avoid that. Thanks.

Comment: No, the paddingLeft separates the icon from the margin of the list. In fact, the part of the view that doesn't get colored is the right part. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you have a parent layout for your adapter view.

So give the `android:background="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"` to layout or ImageView or TextView.

If you have ImageView and TextView within layout then you can set the background for that layout.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It's not working. I have a LinearLayout, inside of it I have a TableLayout and inside, a TextView and ImageView, when I set the android:background property to TextView/ImageView (or entire TableLayout or LinearLayout) the color is only on the element not in the entire ListView width, and I have all the controls width at fill_parent...

Comment: don't give paddingleft for your tablelayout.

Comment: Is the right part the one that doesn't get colored. The paddingLeft is por separate the element from the border of the screen

Comment: give paddingleft to imageview and adjust textview based on that. Otherwise put that tableview inside relativelayout and make relative width match parent. Also remove the background for tableview and set it for relativelayout.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks so much!

Comment: Even you can give paddingleft to tablerow and set background for tablelayout.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to remove these lines .

```
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/primary" />
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
```

And set list Selector not background

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/yourlist_selector"
```

and set property `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` inside listView in xml .

Comment: No, It removes from the listView the selected Item and still colors just the element not the width of the listview